# Automatically reboot a server when the CPU usage is <90%

Tags: 16.04, aws

I have AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04 server) and i'm using a service on it. Sometimes, the server hangs and the CPU usage stuck on 75% and the only way to get it work is by rebooting it.

Is there any script that allows me to automatically reboot the server when the CPU usage is < 90% ?

Comment: This sounds like a *terribly* poor workaround. A better solution would be to figure out why it hangs, and at worst restart *that* service.